# Почему переменная выводит 0, хотя отладчик показывает другое значение переменной

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия, стандарт

Если использовать такой код:

```
void outputResultsCalculation(double initialX, double finalX, double stepX, double epsilon)
{
   double deltaX = initialX, amountRow;
   int numberMemberRow;

   for (deltaX; checkValuesX(stepX, deltaX, finalX); deltaX += stepX)
   {
       amountRow = 0;
       numberMemberRow = 0;

       cout << deltaX << ":\n"
           << "Функция: " << log(1 - deltaX) << endl
           << "Цикл: " << getSumRowCycle(deltaX, epsilon) << endl
           << "Рекурсия: " << getSumRowRecursion(deltaX, amountRow, numberMemberRow, epsilon) << 
"\nВызывается: " << numberMemberRow << " раз\n";
       cout << endl;
   }
}
```

то переменная numberMemberRow будет выводить 0, а если такой:

```
void outputResultsCalculation(double initialX, double finalX, double stepX, double epsilon)
{

double deltaX = initialX, amountRow;
int numberMemberRow;

for (deltaX; checkValuesX(stepX, deltaX, finalX); deltaX += stepX)
{
    amountRow = 0;
    numberMemberRow = 0;

    cout << deltaX << ":\n"
        << "Функция: " << log(1 - deltaX) << endl
        << "Цикл: " << getSumRowCycle(deltaX, epsilon) << endl
        << "Рекурсия " << numberMemberRow << " раза вызывается\nРезультат: " << 
    getSumRowRecursion(deltaX, amountRow, numberMemberRow, epsilon) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

то все нормально будет выводиться.
Переменная numberMemberRow подсчитывает количество вызовов рекурсивной функции, вот ее код:

```
double getSumRowRecursion(double deltaX, double& amountRow, int& numberMemberRow, double epsilon)
{
numberMemberRow++;
double memberRow = pow(deltaX, numberMemberRow) / -numberMemberRow;

if (abs(memberRow) >= epsilon && numberMemberRow <= 3970)
{
    amountRow += memberRow;
    return getSumRowRecursion(deltaX, amountRow, numberMemberRow, epsilon);
}
else
    return amountRow;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, ваш компилятор еще не знает, что в С++17 вычисления в цепочке `<<` должны выполняться в том порядке, в котором записаны, и пользуется своим правом вычислять их так, как это ему удобно - например, сначала взяв значение `numberMemberRow` для вывода, а уже потом вычисляя `getSumRowRecursion`. Попробуйте разбить вывод на части, типа:

```
cout << deltaX << ":\n"
     << "Функция: " << log(1 - deltaX) << endl;
cout << "Цикл: " << getSumRowCycle(deltaX, epsilon) << endl;
cout << "Рекурсия: " << getSumRowRecursion(deltaX, amountRow, numberMemberRow, epsilon);
cout << "\nВызывается: " << numberMemberRow << " раз\n";
```

Comment: Использование в одном выражении и функции с побочными эффектами и результатов этих побочных эффектов, это вообще плохая практика.

Comment: Пишу в VS 2019. Не думал что он будет отставать в плане нововведений

Comment: Герман Борисов, вы про функцию checkValuesX?

Comment: @NeedLive С 2019 дела пока не имел, но 2017 по умолчанию **не** включает все новые стандарты, нужно указывать ему явно, с чем работать будем...

Comment: @NeedLive, я про `getSumRowRecursion(…, numberMemberRow, …)` и `numberMemberRow`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, Почему?

Comment: @NeedLive, чтобы не попадать в описанную ситуацию. Не во всех ситуациях стандарт дает гарантию на порядок вычисления. И у разных версий стандарта эти гарантии разные. Проще вычислять поочередно, чем выучить наизусть все правила. Дополнительный материал на русском есть тут: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, спасибо, учту